# Override a hardcoded link with Jquery or CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can I override, hide, make invisible, or change the hardcoded links in my footer using CSS or jquery? The disclaimer link points to an out-of-date wrong page hardcoded in the masterpage which I don't have security access to, but I do have the security rights to add a CSS or jscript code to the page itself.

```
<span class="FooterPipe">|</span>
<span class="FooterText">
    <a class="footerA" href="Javascript:newWin('http://global.xyz.com/inc/disclaimer.aspx')">Disclaimer</a>
</span>
<span class="FooterPipe">|</span>

<span class="FooterText">
    <a class="footerA" href="Javascript:newWin('http://global.xyz.com/inc/privacy.aspx')">Privacy</a>
</span>
```

Comment: You could target the specific url if you really wanted with something like `a[href=Javascript:newWin('http://global.xyz.com/inc/disclaimer.aspx')]`

Comment: Please note that search engines will not pick up the new link, and thus will still index the out-of-date page. You could fix that by adding a 301 though. But if you add a 301 anyway, the script to change the url isn't needed anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You can hide it using CSS like so:

```
a.footerA { display: none; }
```

Or remove it from the DOM completely using jQuery:

```
$('a.footerA').first().remove();
```

Or simply change the HREF attribute using jQuery:

```
$('a.footerA').first().attr('href', 'the/new/page.html');
```

Comment: If I understand the OPs question, he only wants to hide the 'Disclaimer' link, not both of them.

Comment: Updated examples to select the first matching element. @op you could also match on the link text with something like `('a.footerA:contains(disclaimer)')`

Comment: Good comment of @RoryMcCrossan: to select only the disclaimer use this selector: `$('.FooterText').first().find('.footerA')`

Comment: The CSS example I posted would hide both. But regardless of that, I would recommend using javascript to handle this. It's not ideal, but it will work just fine cross-browser if you need to put a band aid on this problem.